# skipping unknown items while Serializing using json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to serialize obj using json (Python). I wish to skip json's unknown type 
I know I can add my own encoder, but what I'm interested in is to just skip the unknown type. I don't want to use `None` instead. I have tried

```
icon=QIcon()        
arr=["blablal",icon]    
str1=simplejson.dumps(arr,skipkeys=True)
```

I used the skipkeys option to skip the icon object which is unknown type for json but I keep getting TypeError exception.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i found the problem

icon isn't a key but a value 
if icon was used as a key in a dict it would have been ignored